# Flutter: How to make circular avatar in appbar

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day, I am struggling to make my avatar in the top right of the appbar a perfect circle. It keeps coming out oval.

[image]

I've tried many options (including setting the radius, using ClipRRect, ClipOval, etc) and it doesn't seem to affect the shape of the rounded edges.

Code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: COLORS_BG,
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('images/localhourlogo.png', height: 50.0,),
          ]
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        PopupMenuButton<String>(
          icon: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(googleUserUrl)
          ),
          onSelected: choiceAction,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return MenuItems.choices.map((String choice) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String> (
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        )
      ],
```

**Goal:** to make the avatar a pure circle and not this oval shape.

**Tried:** ClipRRect, ClipOval, setting radius min and max, etc

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Are you sure the image is not oval?

Comment: Are you speaking about the CircleAvatar Widget? By default it is a circle, not an oval shape. Either your image has a shape that is not fitting or you are changing the shape with your own changes. As you can see here: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/cba1149f189df8eed9e29953acb4f4fd

Comment: The image is square, originally, as that is how it appears without the CircleAvatar

Comment: I've tested a bit more and it's AppBar Widget that's doing that to your avatar. I'm pretty sure we can fix it. Give me a few mins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this issue in the past and have found that wrapping the AvatarCircle in a container with 58 width fixes the Circle radius ratio issue, making it a proper circle shape. One pixel more or less may fit your liking. Give this a try:

```
Container(
  width: 58,
  child: PopupMenuButton(
    icon: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
        "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Jx21kNqFSTU/UXemtqPhZCI/AAAAAAAAh74/BMGSzpU6F48/s1600/funny-cat-pictures-047-001.jpg"
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return [
        PopupMenuItem<String> (
          value: '1',
          child: Text('1'),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem<String> (
          value: '2',
          child: Text('2'),
        ),
      ];
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: This still results in my image becoming oval, sadly.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: I've put a solution below showing the three comparisons

Comment: I've changed my response. I've swapped the Container to be around the PopupMenuButton instead of around the CircleAvatar and now it looks like a circle. These two widgets really don't like working together.

Comment: I took the suggestion of wrapping it in a container, but keeping the ClipOval widget and it has worked well. Using CircleAvatar has still made it oval in shape. I've added in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it should work with `ClipRRect`. Make sure you add `fit: BoxFit.cover` to avoid scaling.

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
  child: Image.network(
    googleUserUrl,
    height: 50.0,
    width: 50.0,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I found, but now my issue is that I can't make the avatar bigger than what is shown below.

```
actions: <Widget>[
                  PopupMenuButton<String>(
                    icon: Container(
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Align(
                          heightFactor: 1,
                          widthFactor: 1,
                          child: Image.network(googleUserUrl),
                        ),
                      )
                    ),
```

[image]

---

**With João Soares code:**

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
  width: 58,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
      "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Jx21kNqFSTU/UXemtqPhZCI/AAAAAAAAh74/BMGSzpU6F48/s1600/funny-cat-pictures-047-001.jpg"
    )
  ),
),
```

[image]

---

**With dumazy code:**

```
actions: <Widget>[
                  PopupMenuButton<String>(
                    icon: Container(
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Align(
                          heightFactor: 1,
                          widthFactor: 1,
                          child: Image.network(googleUserUrl),
                        ),
                      )
                    ),
```

[image]

---

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution thanks in big part to João Soares. Adjusting the width increases the size of the circle. I made it equal to the height of the "localhour" image, and now it looks great.

```
actions: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 60.0,
                    child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                      icon: ClipOval(
                        child: Align(
                          heightFactor: 1,
                          widthFactor: 1,
                          child: Image.network(googleUserUrl),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onSelected: choiceAction,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return MenuItems.choices.map((String choice) {
                          return PopupMenuItem<String> (
                            value: choice,
                            child: Text(choice),
                          );
                        }).toList();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
```

[image]

Comment: It's odd that you had to user a ClipOval. I tried my solution with your code and it worked. If an answer fixed you issue, please don't forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: Can only mark mine as correct in 2 days apparently.

Comment: So my answer wasn't correct? I don't understand. I used your code, changed the answer to match you wanted. I think it's not very fair that you get help from two people but then you will mark your own answer as correct and don't even upvote the people who helped you.

Comment: Apologies. I will mark yours as correct, since it helped me find the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClipOval Widget to do that. I am posting an example where my image will be leading icon widget in rounded format just like in native android.

```
AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
      leading: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Image(image: Image.asset('assets/images/icon.webp').image,),
        ),
      ),
    );
```